# Cannot find "IsComposeExtensionQuery()" method, when I develop a messaging extension

Tags: microsoft-teams

I followed the C# sample code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions#net) . NuGet package Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams has been added, but I still got error saying that IsComposeExtensionQuery() method does not exist.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: yes. i am using asp.net core and created the project by "dotnet new webapi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error when I was building a messaging extension using aspnet core, mainly because the package Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams does not support .Net standard at the moment.
My solution is to copy the code from its repo. https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams
Actually it seems the code in that repo supports .Net standard, but has not been published to nuget. Hope it can be published soon.